# Deleted branch still appears in other instance of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013

So we're using TFS2013 and I created a test folder, then added a test file to it, then converted the folder to a branch and then deleted the branch. (I did this to see what would happen if you try to delete a branch that has files checked out). But when I open TFS on another machine I still see that branch. Locally it's disappeared from view, but on the remote server (our build server) it still shows up as being there. I checked out the test file on the remote machine and then deleted the branch on my local machine, so I thought it was still appearing because I had pending changes, but I undid them, refreshed source control explorer and even closed and reopened VS and it still appears there. I checked with another developer and he doesn't see it, but I still don't understand why it's appearing on the build server.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check in the Pending Changes after deleting the branch, otherwise the branch will not be deleted from remote server.

For other client machines which ever connected to the project, you need to **Get Latest Version** from the remote server to delete the existing local branch. (Sync with remote server to delete the branch)

Comment: Thanks. It resolved itself. I did check in the changes, but I don't think I got latest.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the branch in Visua Studio then select "View History". 
On the top of the list you should see the changeset related to the deletion, Right-click on it then select "Get This Version".